# Qubits in quantum computing

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, hilbert-space, quantum-computer

In my picture of the quantum computers, the memory would deal with matter in superposition. The matters actual state is said be precisely unknown and you cannot cleary say it is in this state or another, but only to a degree this or to a degree not this. In conventional computers, the memory addresses are either in one of two states this or not this.

My question is this then a quantum computer must have memory states of just fuzzy. This could be described as (1 and 0) if the quantum computers memory is said to be a state of uncertainty all the memory qubits would all be in the same state of fuzziness. How could you then differentiate between the state of each qubit and use this to represent a variety of information? Is it therefore that each qubit's state would have to be in a different degree of uncertainty to another? And with this, would it mean that you could differenciate between qubit's, and use this to represent a variety of information?

Finally then a quantum computer with a finite number of qubit's must have a memory which has an infinite amount of possible states because of the limitless degrees of uncertainty a qubit can be in?

Comment: I am not clear about what  you are asking. Please make it clear

Comment: That in order to determine what something is it has to obsevered to be this or that (to be or not to be) surely something that is not clearly defined and in two states at the same time the things description can only be described as fuzzy and vague.

Comment: I suggest to break up your text into smaller sentences. I wished to fix it, but honestly I simply can't decode where ends a statement and where the next begins. It is like your text had been generated by a spam engine.

Comment: @peterh the grammar in my comment or in the question or both. Sorry I find it difficult composing something while using a mobile phone.

Comment: @Bobs Also I use mobile, but I wouldn't ever post a question without proper formatting. Yes, I know it is hard, particularly on the apple ones where you have to fight the spellchecker instead of it would help you. But the main problem what I see: I start to read your first sentence... I read the first line, then the second, I don't know where it started but the newer and newer words are coming and coming. You should at least use some ","s. In [compound sentences](http://examples.yourdictionary.com/compound-sentence-examples.html), they separate the clauses.

Comment: If you want your question to be taken seriously given the comments above you'll have to do find a proper keyboard to make appropriate edits.  @peterh is absolutely spot on: in its current form near impossible to read.

Comment: Are you familiar with Bloch sphere representation?

Comment: It seems no urges, no advices can get you to fix your question. Are you really wanting to get answer? Is it a real question?

Comment: @peterh I have altered my question. But due to the nature of the topic it's difficult to describe clearly the concepts. I am thus at a loss  However i have included in the question the desire for someone to point me in the right direction if my description about the topic is incorrect or rather differs from what is actually the case. Please therefore if my question is not real can you point me to some area of knowledge that will help me rectify my unreal picture of things and help me clarify my thoughts. I have no intention of being smart and profound  I only wish to further my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

First for all, saying it has three possible states is completely wrong as 1 and 0 are also superposition of 0 and 1. And yes, the major problem in quantum computation is that the information is computed in superposition's and we cannot measure the state exactly and there is only a probability of measuring a particular state.But this is also the advantage.

To compute something ,we don't have to apply a gate(like not gate for a bit flip) to each and every bit like in conventional computer but we can just create a superposition of everything we want and then apply the gate once.The nature will take care of the rest.This result in exponential increase in computation.For n bits, the computation power is equivalent to $2^n$ classical bits. Actually, if you have 200 qubit computer, then you have more computational power than whole of the world combined.But making algorithms for quantum computers is different and more difficult.To learn more,you can check our grover's search algorithm and shor's algorithm for prime number factorization.Because the final result correctness is probabilistic,you always have to take care of the errors that will be present.

Comment: I understand that when observing at the quantum level there are degrees of certainty as to the state of something which manifest s in a probability of something's state ie it's position is there but you become more uncertain of where it's going. So does applying the not gate reverse what you observe of the the degree of state of all the

Comment: The super position of "things" at once

Comment: I think you should learn a little bit about quantum computing.See wazirani lectures on quantum computing on edx. We don't measure the  position and momentum of the qubit simultaneously but just measure, for example the state of polarization in a photon or the energy state of an atom and these act as our qubits. I am not talking about the uncertainity principle here which you seem to be referring to.Also google hadamard gate for quantum computers.

Comment: Sorry for badgering you but isn't the uncertainty principle responsible for inaccuracies in measurment of the energy state of an atom or photon. Never mind I'll delve into some more thankyou

Comment: I'll try and explain my self some more when you measure something you get a quantity back but as I understand it this quantity is fuzzy because of the HUP, or is the quantity you measure the exact state of the photon or atom and you needn't worry about the HUP.

Comment: Or the quantity you measure is only likely to be the state of the atom at point of measurment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I think I can answer part of my own question 1 and 0 are simply the extremes of the superposition and are when the degree of uncertainty to that state is reducing and becoming more certain.